# Why was the Hamlet question closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closing, close-reasons

I was browsing some questions, and I noticed that [Given an infinite number of monkeys and an infinite amount of time, would one of them write Hamlet?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/given-an-infinite-number-of-monkeys-and-an-infinite-amount-of-time-would-one-of) was closed because it was off topic.

While it is phrased in a colloquial manner, it does seem to be mathematics, see [The Infinite Monkey Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_monkey_theorem), so why was it closed as off topic?

Comment: cf. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1514

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Good point. Is this a duplicate then?

Comment: Not at all. It is just that part of the reason for the closure was my plea on the meta, which makes it somewhat relevant to your question.

Comment: cf. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3194/why-was-the-hamlet-question-reopened?lq=1

Comment: Perhaps because to some people mathematics and a sense of fun are incompatible. I am of the opposite opinion.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would guess that the reason is to prevent new answers, which would likely not add anything to the existing discussion. That question attracts a little too much attention.

Comment: Why don't we just lock it instead?

Answer (score 2):

The only reason for closing I have noticed articulated is to prevent junk answers (I might not be observant about other reasons, but at least it seems to be *a* main reason).  If I count correctly, during the over 2 years it was open from Nov 2011 to Jan 2014, 4 answers were posted, all 4 in Nov 2011, so none had come in during the last 2 years before closing.  I am in favor of reopening with protected status, unless and until I am aware of an actual problem to solve by closing.

Comment: I would still like to see [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/17179) deleted.